# How many died during St. Lawrence Island 1878-1880 famine?

Tags: famine, alaska

Do we have any accurate figures of deaths during the 1878-1880 St. Lawrence Island famine?

[Wikipedia states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Lawrence_Island) the population had been decimated, but attributes that to both deaths and migration.

[Encyclopedia Arctica](http://collections.dartmouth.edu/arctica-beta/html/EA12-04.html) states

> These are the remnants of a much larger population which was greatly
>   reduced by a severe epidemic and famine which struck in the winter of
>   1878-79, killing hundreds of people then living in villages on all
>   sides of the island. Since then the entire eastern end as well as most
>   of the north and south coasts of the island have been uninhabited.

Comment: I have added some links and a quotation.

Answer (score 2):

The original report comes from [Report of the cruise of the U.S. revenue steamer Thomas Corwin, in the Arctic Ocean, 1881](https://archive.org/details/reportofcruiseof02unit), by Calvin Leighton (C.L.) Hooper, of the US Revenue Cutter Service.

I found this by reviewing the references in the OP:

> In that year Capt. C. L. Hooper, in command of the U.S. Revenue
>   Steamer Corwin, stopped At. St. Lawrence to investigate reports of
>   starvation of large numbers of Eskimos during the winter of 1878-79.
>   Capt. Hooper has given a vivid description of the distressing
>   conditions he found (Hooper, 1881).

[The St. Lawrence Island Famine and Epidemic, 1878-80: A Yupik Narrative in Cultural and Historical Context](http://www.jstor.org/stable/40316652) reports that at least 1,000 lives were lost.